# In Java EE full container, performance wise, is it better to pass an object around or just let the Entity Manager get it from memory?

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, glassfish, eclipselink

If I know that a lot of subfunctions are going to use a database object, should I get the object in my main method and then pass it to all the subfunctions to reuse, or is it much of a hit to just get it from the Entity Manager when I actually need it?

I have a multiple layers of iterators, and the object isn't being used until the lowest level. Right now I am getting it on the top level and passing it through 4 layers of methods before actually using it.

The real problem is I would like to use one of the middle functions in another part of the program, and instead of making a needless call to get that object. I would just call the function.

The layout is something like this:

```
generate()
    MyObj obj = getMyObj(); // Entity Manager find

    generateSubItems(obj)
        generateSubSubItems(obj)
            generateSubSubItemValues(obj)
                // Use obj
```

The problem is I want to use generateSubSubItems without having to call getMyObj() if I can because I have to use it quite a few places. I don't really want to be spreading out dependent code all over the place for one, and for two it mucks up the code in the other places which I would like to keep as clean as possible.

Would it be a huge performance hit to do this:

```
generate()
    generateSubItems()
        generateSubSubItems()
            generateSubSubItemValues()
                MyObj obj = getMyObj(); // Entity Manager find

                // Use obj
```

I am using EclipseLink, Glassfish, and SOFT caching.

USAGE: It would be used several hundred times per call to generateSubSubItemValues(). This would get called several hundred times a day most likely.

So it would add up. Especially as the software grows.

Answer (score 0):

It is still Java even in Java EE, you are passing just the reference to the object, so it is not a huge deal in terms of performance, if not reference you would need to pass the some id which would probably take as much space on the stack.

Comment: Except if you are passing the object around you already have it. If you are using the entity manager to get it every time, it has to go to the memory and do the work to get it and give it back. What I'm wondering is if that is a huge hit to performance to do that thousands of times a day when it could be hundreds.

Comment: I am confused, you posted two scenarios, one in which you get your object at the begginign and pass it arround and second when you get it at the end of the chain. Both are comparable in costs. If you are asking about getting object in each method of the chain, that yes it is more costly, but if it is the same EM, it is already in its context, so it is just a look up of some map. Probably nothing comparing with all JEE overhead.

Comment: Sure, I understand it is comparable in cost, except in the first version it happens once and then passes the object down to the lowest level in the chain which uses it 500 - 1000 times. In the second example it would get it 500 - 1000 times. "yes it is more costly, but if it is the same EM, it is already in its context, so it is just a look up of some map. Probably nothing comparing with all JEE overhead" This is exactly what I was asking. Is the Entity Manager efficient enough to just pull the cache from a map or does it have to run checks for cache consistency and other things like that?

Comment: If you have it just pass it. Not so much of the EM look up as for all the injections on the way (you functions will need the EM to find the object), the wiring costs more than lookup. And finally is so implementation dependent that you just have to test it with your setup. From the OOP, if the generate subItems methods decoreate your object it is better when it is past explicit than retrieved as at least the 'side' effect are more obvious than when it is just an id.